# Read .csv file and make all values float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

I have a `.csv` file that contains only rows with cashflows in different lengths.
I have a function that calculates the cashflow's NPVs, and all I have left is to calculate NPVs for all rows in the dataframe. However, running the code only returns "NaN" and I couldn't find out why.

I assume 2 problems could arise from my code:

1. It wasn't imported as float values
2. It wasn't able to deal with different lengths of cashflows.

Code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv('cashflowT1.csv',index_col=0)
e = math.e
r = 0.1
    
# function to calculate NPV with continous compunding
def npv(cashflow, r):
   '''calculate NPV with continous compunding'''
   a = []
   for i in range(len(cashflow)):
      a.append(float(cashflow[i]) * e**((-r)*i))
   return sum(a)
   
print(npv(df.iloc[0],r))


# what I wish my dataframe looked like after csv reading:
# df = [[-500,100,500,200,10],
#     [300,400,500,600,700],
#     [-12000,3500,3500,3500,3500,3500,3500,3500,3500,3500]]

# what I wish happened:
# (-500)*e**(-0.1)*1 + 100*e**(-0.1)*2 + 500*e**(-0.1)*3 ...
```

Comment: add sample data and expected otuput

Comment: FYI, the `i = i+1` in your `for` loop doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: also you keep rewriting new values to `a` and return only the last value. If this is what you want you better define your function as `i = len(cashflow) a = float(cashflow[-1]) * e**`...

Comment: A dataframe has columns and rows. it can't have different lengths. What does your file look like? Assuming you have a dataframe, you can apply the equation to each series directly: `df['colA']*e**(-r*df.index)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, might have not explained well. that file has rows, and every row has an independent cashflow (coloumns have no meaning). I wish to make every row a list.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos only works if the index is reset and is a good solution then. In the code the csv is read with the option index_col=0 which might be something quite different from 0,1,2,...

Comment: @konstanze there's no CSV or even a dataframe in the code. `df` is a nested list, loaded in some way *other* than `read_csv`. If that way was modified to load series instead of lists, the same vectorized expression would apply to a series

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos ???? line 4 `df = pd.read_csv('cashflowT1.csv',index_col=0)`

Comment: The question is still missing sample contents of "cashflowT1.csv".

Answer (score 1):

```
def npv(cashflow, r):
  '''calculate NPV with continous compunding'''
  a = []
  for i in range(len(cashflow)):
    a.append(float(cashflow[i]) * e**((-r)*i))
  return a
```

might get you a step closer.

this will return lists, which you then need to write to your dataframe (instead of print())

```
df['new'] = [npv(row,r) for row in df.itertuples()]
```

will write the output `a` to a new column in your dataframe

Comment: You don't need that loop. Besides, what does the file actually contain?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos what makes you think the loop isn't needed?

Comment: Vectorization. `df['colA']*e**(-r*df.index)`. What the OP posted isn't a dataframe, it's a nested list

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos ok, I see why you say this. I thinks it's an inaccuracy in the OP, they explicitely as for a dataframe. For a nested list I fully agree